# Interpreting difficult linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

What does this statement do? It is the last line that has me baffled.

```
    foreach (View_ManSchedAllocatedTask task in
              manualScheduleData.GetAllocatedTasks(DateTime.Now)
                                .Where(x => !x.Status.Equals("999B"))
                                .Where(x => x.LetterSent == false)
                                .Where(x => x.Stage.Equals(missed ? "51" : "06")))
```

Comment: Its a [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx check conditional operator.

Comment: `missed ? "51" : "06"` means, if `missed` is `true` use "51" else use "06".

Answer (score 4):

I'll explain the line:

```
.Where(x => x.Stage.Equals(missed ? "51" : "06"))
```

The object `x` has a property `Stage`. If that `Stage` is equal to *something* it is inside the result set, otherwise `x` is outside the result set.

Now what is this *something* `x.Stage` has to be equal to?

If `missed` is `true`, it must be equal to `"51"`, otherwise `"06"`.

The value of `missed` is an invariant, so all elements in the result set will either have `Stage` `"51"` or `"06"` depending on `missed`.

The ternary operator is defined as follows:

```
result = expression ? truthy_value : falsy_value

::=

if (expression)
{
    result = truthy_value;
} else {
    result = falsy_value;
}
```

The `::=` means **is equal to**.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably the ternary statement that is somewhat confusing.

```
Where(x => x.Stage.Equals(missed ? "51" : "06"))
```

it basically means

`if missed = true` check for `x.Stage.equals(51)`

`if missed = false` check for `x.Stage.equals(06)`

Answer (score 1):

It's using the [Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) which is like a short-hand 'if' statement.

So, It's the same as this:

```
var stageToCompare = "";

if(missed == true)
    stageToCompare = "51";
else
    stageToCompare = "06";


foreach (View_ManSchedAllocatedTask task in manualScheduleData.GetAllocatedTasks(DateTime.Now)
    .Where(x => !x.Status.Equals("999B"))
    .Where(x => x.LetterSent == false)
    .Where(x => x.Stage.Equals(stageToCompare)));
```

Comment: It's actually known as `conditional operator` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to visualize with the ternary operator (`?:`) expanded into an `if` statement:

```
.Where(x => x.Stage.Equals(missed ? "51" : "06")))
```

is equivalent to:

```
.Where(
    x =>
    {
        if (missed)
        {
            return x.Stage.Equals("51");
        }
        else
        {
            return x.Stage.Equals("06");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The given statement iterates loop for all the task those are allocated at current time stamp, whose status is not '999B', its LetterSent is false and stage is 51 or 06 (according to value of missed as explained above.)

Answer (score 0):

Its only including data where `Stage` is either `"51"` or `"06"` depending on whether the `missed` variable is `true` or `false`.